# Need help locating data buried within HTML table with no IDs (Selenium/Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The page is a real estate website that I want to pull the data from listings from. http://www.josephbernard.net/properties.php?state=oregon

I would like to pull the data in the hyperlink in these cells:

```
newProperties = []
...

<td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">$725,000</td>

<td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> Available</td>

*<td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <a href="/washington">


 Washington Street Studios
<br>1410 Washington Street SW<br>Albany, Oregon, 97321
</a>
</td>*

<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">15</td>

<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">8.49%</td>

<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">$48,333</td>

</tr>
```

So then I could append to newProperties:

```
newProperties.append({
    'title': "Washington Street Studios",
    'URL': "(/washington)"
    'location': "Albany, Oregon, 8731"
})
```

The only problem in the parent nodes don't seem to have any ID's or classes I could properly target them by.  Any ideas how I could do this one?

Comment: looks like you are going to have to parse the table   perhaps this helps. https://jsperf.com/parse-table-jquery-each-vs-for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

This page is full of nested tables. Each of the listings are in a TABLE so you need to find the right tables by CSS selector. Then check and see if there are 2 links inside (the first link is always the picture) and sometimes the address isn't linked. If there are two, then the 2nd link is the one you are looking for.

```
listings = driver.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table[style='border-bottom:#ccc 1px solid;']")
for listing in listings
    links = listing.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    if len(links) > 1
        // do something with links[1]
```